# Low Search: Ignore query params?

Tags: low-search

I have a primary exp:low_search:results loop which the user can filter using low search form. The form updates the URL using normal query strings. So /index?foo=bar displays matches where field foo is equal to bar.

Simultaneously, I have a Count in the header which tallies all matches from that same channel with a certain special criteria:

```
{exp:low_search:results channel="my_channel" status="special_status"}{if count == 1}{total_results}{/if}{/exp:low_search:results}
```

My issue is that when we pass "?foo=bar" in the URL, there is no way to avoid having it affect the count query as well. So the count is incorrect on results pages for this channel.

We also have a global search page using a "keywords=foo" query parameter, and it affects the count query too. Is there a way we can tell the count query to ignore parameters in the URL, or must we re-write the count query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using GET variables (ie. not encoding the query), then there's currently no way to ignore the search params; they will always be applied. If you must ignore them, use encoded queries and omit the `query=""` parameter.

As a sidenote: use `{absolute_results}` when paginating results to get the correct result count.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, and appreciate the tip for absolute_results. I think I see a strategy with a custom low search filter that is last in the parse order, which ignores the entry_ids that are passed to it and just does a raw count, or perhaps something with exp:query. I’ll reply back here with what I come up with for future reference.

Comment: You could also create an extension using the low_search_pre_search hook and optionally empty out the parameters with `ee()->low_search_params->reset();`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the total posts in the channel, as opposed to the total search results in the channel?

If so use a standard `channel:entries` tag to get your total, then use the search results tag for the results?

Comment: For both tags, we apply several filters, including a custom Low Search filter. Sorry, should have been more clear about that.

Beginning of Primary Loop:

{exp:low_search:results channel="my_channel"} (With several parameters applied via the url)

Beginning of Count loop:
{exp:low_search_results channel="my_channel" params="special_param"} (Want to ignore query params)

Comment: Hi Ty, so yea i I understand wouldn't my idea be relivent? instead of trying to count the results of the search,  minus the filters applied to the search, you would count the entries in a channel:entries loop, not the search results loop. Can you provide a more in depth template example? Or even an idea on the 'special_params'??

Comment: Hey, the reason is that the special param is a custom low search param we wrote which filters based on special criteria – we cannot replicate the same loop using exp:channel:entries. Thank you though.